# How does one loop through a set of string value names in a registry key?

Tags: vbscript, registry

I need to use VBScript to loop through a set of registry string value names located within a specific key, such as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and delete all the string values except for the ones that I specify.

I was able to successfully delete a specific string value using `DeleteValue` and specifying the name of the string value. However, I would like to loop through each string value, get its name, check it and delete it if, for example, `strValueName != "ccApp"`. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: First of all, I'd ask "why" you want to remove all values in a key except for {X}. Especially given your choice of example key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that iterates through the key and outputs info to a file:

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Scripting/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/2004-03/0353.html